# Can i use application/json over application/json; charset=UTF-8 safely?

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser, chromium, content-type

There is an old problem, that some browsers or HTTP clients did not interpret correctly `UTF-8` special characters. To avoid it, we declare `charset` explicitly:

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Since the problem is fixed in Chromium, is it safe to skip charset and use raw header:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

Or some browsers/clients still may not interpret `UTF-8` special characters correctly?

Comment: That depends _entirely_ on the consumers of your JSON data. We can't say for sure. Is this JSON _only_ being loaded by web-browsers, or is it also being loaded by other client software?

Comment: It being loaded by IOS/Android applications as well

Comment: Then it depends on how those apps were built. If their code was written (incorrectly, I note, as JSON is implicitly UTF-8) to require the `charset` attribute or otherwise assume a different default encoding then you should retain the `charset` parameter. There is no harm in retaining it.